# FQL: Get newest posts by friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I try to get the newest posts/news by friends (status updates, new picture posts, etc.)

I'm using the following method, but it also returns news of user-liked pages/movies, etc. - I only want to get the news of friends.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0  LIMIT 50
```

Has anyone an idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, message FROM stream 
  WHERE filter_key ='newsfeed' AND is_hidden = 0 
  AND type IN (46,56) LIMIT 50
```

A type of 46 is a status update and a type of 56 is a post on another user's wall.

You could add or subtract different `type`s as needed. See the [stream documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream) for more details.

BTW, `newsfeed` is a built-in `filter_key` constant. You don't need the subquery to return this.